# How can I save switch state?

Tags: swift

I want to save my switch state on this code, I've been using other solutions but none of these works.

EDIT:

This is how I have it so far, check it out Michael. (This is on UITableViewController)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    switchController.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")
}

@IBAction func changeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(switchController.isOn, forKey: "isDarkMode");
    if switchController.isOn {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]//user global variable
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black //user global variable
        celltext.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]//user global variable
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default //user global variable
        celltext.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Please be more specific. Also, it seems like you have a lot of irrelevant code in your question. Please reduce the code to [a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh yea sorry, what I mean is that I want the switch state to save when I close the app or when I go to another view.

Comment: I think what you want in your `changeSwitch()` is `UserDefaults.standard.set(switch.isOn, forKey: "isDarkMode")` and the setting of the value should be done in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @Michael I don't understand... I'm new at this sorry

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save the value in `viewWillDisappear` in your ViewController.

This function will automatically be called when the viewcontroller is about to disappear from the screen, so by saving the switch state here, you can make sure that the switch state is always saved before the switch would disappear.

```
class BaseTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    ...
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(switchController.isOn, forKey: "isDarkMode")
    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes, shows EXC_BREAKPOINT

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and check what is the actual error. Also, on which line does this error occur?

Comment: Well, first, I did put that code on my BaseTableViewController (my .swift file never had that override func viewWillDisappear thing, so I added it myself with that code you sent me), then I ran it and it crashes when I go to that scene, then in Xcode it shows "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100f97b50)" at line 33.

Comment: Can we go to a chat or something where I can show you how my code is going?

Comment: You can edit your question with the modified code if it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")
if isDarkMode == true {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isDarkMode")
} else { UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isDarkMode")}
```

write `UserDefaults.standard.set(switch.isOn, forKey: "isDarkMode")`. This should go before your `if switchController.isOn == true {}`-statement. Now this is only called when the state is `true`. This makes sure that the saved state is the one that is displayed to the user. And in your viewDidLoad put in

```
switch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")
```

Comment: When I put that instead of my code, it gets an error that says "Expected expression in list of expressions", and on the viewDidLoad it gets a EXC_BREAKPOINT.

Comment: I didn't pay attention on your declaration. Of course in your `viewDidLoad` it should be `switchController.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")` (I don't know why my code compiled in the first place...). and in the `changeSwitch` it should be `UserDefaults.standard.set(switch.isOn, forKey: "isDarkMode"); if switchController.isOn { self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false; /*...*/ } else {/*...*/}`

Comment: you mean "UserDefaults.standard.set(switchController.isOn, forKey: "isDarkMode");", switchController instead of switch?

Comment: check my question again and see how I have it, now it crashes when opening the app.